# Circumcenter of Tetrahedron (in 4D)

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

I am trying to calculate the circumcenter of a tetrahedron in 4 dimensional space. I was hoping for some concrete mathematical formula which can make this calculation more accurate.

Comment: Am I confused? First of all the 4 vertices cannot be coplanar. Let's assume it. Then there is a unique 3-dim affine plane which contains these 4 vertices. In that 3-plane there is a unique 2-sphere $S^2$ which contains the 4 vertices. Every 3-sphere which contains the 4 vertices contains that unique $S^2$. The smallest of such 3-dim spheres has $S^2$ as its equator. Thus the center of $S^2$ is the requested circumcenter. That's it, or is there more to it?

Comment: I am trying to find out the smallest enclosing sphere in 4D which will pass through all 4 vertices of the tetrahedron. Basically I am trying to check if the given tetrahedron is delaunay compliant i.e if any other point lies within the sphere formed around the tetrahedron. The 4 vertices are not co-planar.

Comment: The radii in dimension d for a regular tetrahedron satisfy the recurrence (2r_{d+1})^2(1 -(r_d)^2)=1, with r_1=1/2.  This gives  r_4=sqrt(2/5).

Comment: The tetrahedron can be both regular and irregular.

Comment: So, the tetrahedron is 3-dimensional, but the ambient space is 4-dimensional?

Answer (score 3):

Let the points be $(a1,a2,a3,a4),(b1,b2,b3,b4),(c1,c2,c3,c4),(d1,d2,d3,d4)$.
The circumcentre is in the hyperplane, so it is a convex combination of the points 
$$CC = wA+xB+yC+(1-w-x-y)D$$
The distances to the points are the same.
$$|(1-w)AD-xBD-yCD|^2\\=|-wAD+(1-x)BD-yCD|^2\\=|-wAD-xBD+(1-y)CD|^2\\=|-wAD-xBD-yCD|^2$$
Subtract the last expression from the first three, to get three linear equations in $w,x,y$:
$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}2AD.AD&2AD.BD&2AD.CD\\2BD.AD&2BD.BD&2BD.CD\\2CD.AD&2Cd.BD&2CD.CD\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}w\\x\\y\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c}AD.AD\\BD.BD\\CD.CD\end{array}\right]$$
For example, $2AD.BD=2(d-a).(d-b)$.  Invert the 3x3 matrix, to find $w,x$ and $y$.

Comment: So this can be solved using linear programming in matlab?

Comment: Yes, calculate all those dot-products, and the Matlab command    inv(M)    will do the inverse.

Comment: Is there a generic way of finding the circumcenter for any given object in any number of dimensions?

Comment: With $P$ points in $D$ dimensions, extend to a $P-1\times P-1$ matrix, with the dot-products as you might expect.

Answer (score 1):

This goes well beyond your question, 
but this paper was posted to the arXiv just last week:

> Jean-Daniel Boissonnat, Ramsay Dyer, Arijit Ghosh.
>   "A probabilistic approach to reducing the algebraic
>   complexity of computing Delaunay triangulations."
>   ([*arXiv abstract*](http://arxiv.org/abs/1505.05454)).
>
> ---
>
> Computing Delaunay triangulations in $\mathbb{R}^d$ involves evaluating the so-called in_sphere predicate that determines if a point $x$ lies inside, on or outside the sphere circumscribing $d+1$ points $p_0,\ldots,p_d$. This predicate reduces to evaluating the sign of a multivariate polynomial of degree $d+2$ in the coordinates of the points $x,p_0,\ldots,p_d$. [...]

---

[image: Witness]

---

Searching on the phrases *in_sphere* or *in-sphere* or *insphere* will access
the substantial literature on the topic.

Comment: Hm. But how does this help in finding the circumcenter? I can see this would be helpful if one only needed the circumcenter to compute this in_sphere predicate, but if one really needed the circumcenter?

Comment: @knedlsepp: I was responding to the OP's: "My overall aim is to find the circumcenter and check if any other point within a given data set lies within the sphere." I.e., the OP only wants the circumcenter in order to answer in_sphere queries.

Comment: Oh! It seems I didn't read that well enough!

Answer (score 0):

By virtue of https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2174952/36678, the quadriplanar coordinates of the circumcenter are expressed only in dot-products, and are thus trivially extended to any dimension.

Given the quadriplanar coordinates $q_i$, the circumcenter is trivially retrieved by
$$
C = \frac{\sum_i q_i \alpha_i X_i}{\sum_i q_i \alpha_i}
$$
where $\alpha_i$ are the respective face areas. (That is to say: You'll only need the dot-product expressions from https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2174952/36678).