# Tetrahedron circumcenter in quadriplanar coordinates

Tags: geometry, triangles, coordinate-systems, barycentric-coordinates

The triangle circumcenter is conveniently expressed in [trilinear coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilinear_coordinates) as
$$
\cos\alpha_1 : \cos\alpha_2 : \cos\alpha_3,
$$
where the $\alpha_i$ are the angles opposite of the respective edge in the trilinear system.

Is there a similar expression for the circumcenter in [quadriplanar coordinates](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadriplanarCoordinates.html), i.e., the same concept carried over to tetrahedra?

Comment: It is possible that this kind of question has an answer in some old  documents, such as the "Mathematical Times" (https://archive.org/stream/mathematicalque03unkngoog#page/n12/mode/1up). I would advise you to look as well to barycentrical coordinates which are more common (because they have more properties).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider the tetrahedron

[image]

and let's say we'd like to find out about the quadriplanar coordinate corresponding to point $A$. Let's further assume that the edges are directed like this:
$$
a' = \overrightarrow{AD}, b = \overrightarrow{AC}, c = \overrightarrow{AB}\\
b' = \overrightarrow{BD}, c' = \overrightarrow{DC}, a = \overrightarrow{CB}.
$$
Then the elevation of the circumcenter above the plane spanned by $C, B, D$ is given by
$$
c_A = \\
  (\langle a, b' \rangle \langle b', c' \rangle \langle c, a' \rangle +\\
  \langle b', c' \rangle \langle c', a \rangle \langle a', b \rangle +\\
  \langle c', a \rangle \langle a, b' \rangle \langle b, c \rangle +\\
  \langle a, b' \rangle \langle b', c' \rangle \langle c', a \rangle
  )\\
/ 24\\
/\alpha_{BDC}\\
/ v,
$$
where $v$ is the volume of the tetrahedron and $\alpha_{BDC}$ the area of the face $BDC$.

The same can be done for all other faces.

Since the quadriplanar coordinates are invariant under multiplication, the fixed factors $24$ and $v$ can be left aside.